# 'Promise.all' resolves all the other remaining promises even if some promises cannot be resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider:

```
getTenantDBPromise(dbStore)
.then(actions => {

  Promise.all(actions).then(() => {
    oldTenantsConf = newTenantsConf;
    logger.info("ALL Tenant DB initialized, Returning DB Store");
    resolve(dbStore);
  });
});
```

In this case, even if some actions are failing to resolve, `Promise.all` should still resolve all the other promises.

Comment: Promise.all doesn't resolve promises, it waits for the supplied promises to resolve, then resolves to an array of the resolved promises - also, what does `resolve(dbStore);` mean? where is `resolve` defined?

Comment: that's not how `Promise.all` works,maybe you can try to  modify your actions,for example ,put the possible error code in the `try catch`

Comment: The `resolve` inside the `.then` suggests you're using Promises wrong, and you're not showing enough of your actual code such that you could possibly get help for what you're doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

It's documented that if one Promise fails in Promise.all, all will fail too.